# Why would Windows 10 require daily restart for normal internet speeds

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-10

## Background

Running a clean install of Windows 10 on a 2013 Retina Macbook Pro via Bootcamp.

## Problem

As the day wears on my internet connection (ONLY via my win 10 laptop) gets slower and slower until I simply have to restart the win 10 OS to restore "normal" internet speeds.

## Own Troubleshooting

It is NOT my local network because all the (many) other devices are fine.
It seems to occur irrespective of which browser I use (Edge or Chrome)
Problem relates to wireless network and not ethernet - if I plug in an ethernet cable (without restart) speed is fine again.
My wireless card driver says it is up to date

What should I do?

Comment: Few things to take a look at that may help you get to your answer:

Comment: Few things to take a look at that may help you get to your answer:
- Settings > Network & Internet > Data Usage > Usage details (Might spot something that is gobbling up the data)
- Settings > Network & Internet > Data usage limits ( is this set to anything?)
- Also, may be an issue with the Wi-Fi driver; perhaps see if there is any update

Anyway, worth a try. Good luck

Comment: If you are dual booting on this MacBook, does the other OS have the same problem? If so, the wireless card may be failing. If not dual booting, maybe boot to a Live CD of some sort and see if the issue remains. This will help isolate it to a hardware or Windows 10 specific problem.